# What type of FDA process does a 222nm Kr-Cl excimer UV-C light have to go through

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy

There are plenty of articles and preliminary research about this type of light being able to kill virus as effectively as 254nm UVC light, but not harmful to human skin and eye. This is wonderful news to the current mess created by COVID-19. Not sure whether there are companies already applying for FDA approval, and what kind of process does it need to go through which will basically translate to how long we have to wait to see this available?

Comment: No wonder there are saying that this type of lamps are quite expensive. Not as much probably as in 87. But for this to be available to general public, it for sure has to be affordable.